# Interface of read_character and last_character in STD_FILES

Tags: io, design-by-contract, eiffel

According to a `std_files.e` that I have found, `read_character` requires `not end_of_file`, but it doesn't specify any post-condition; and  `last_character` has no preconditions.  Therefore, what happens if you call `last_character` before calling `read_character`?

Comment: I presume that in theory it is undefine and in practice, it has the default value of a {CHARACTER_8} object (i.e. 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`last_character` will give a default value `'%U'` unless there is some unusual code around, e.g. the code that redefines this feature or accesses an object `input` on `STD_FILES` and reads something without using `STD_FILES`, etc.

Comment: Therefore there is no way to detect a bug where a program calls `last_character` without having called `read_character` beforehand, right?

Comment: Note that this is old code when attributes did not have the ability to have a contract. If we were to rewrite that code today, it would most likely have a precondition.